# Should User class implement IPrincipal and IIdentity

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, iprincipal, iidentity

I'm building my own token based authentication for asp.net web api 2 and I have a question about the `user` class.

Currently my `user` class implements `IPrincipal` and `IIdentity`, but I don't know what is the best practice. Would you divide `IPrincipal` and `IIdentity` and make the `IIdentity` implementation a member of `IPrincipal`?

Currently I use the following class declaration

```
class User : IPrincipal, IIdentity
```

Thank you!

Comment: A class **Implements** an interface - it doesn't **inherit** from it ... any class can only ever **inherit** from a **single** base class (but it can implement multiple interfaces)

Comment: Why not? These are interfaces, they are meant to be implemented. Is your question about implementing both interfaces in the same class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Would you divide IPrincipal and IIdentity and make the IIdentity
>   implementation a member of IPrincipal?

I don't think this is a good approach, since if the `Identity` was similar to `IPrincipal` there shouldn't be any reason for being separated.

Furthermore, as of now your class implements both interfaces. That means your class implements the methods of both interfaces. If you decide later for any reason that your class shouldn't implement one or another interface, you should just have to remove the implementation of the methods that are tied to the interface you want to remove.

In addition to the above keep in mind the following:

> The interface-segregation principle (ISP) states that no client should
>   be forced to depend on methods it does not use

This is one of the five [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) principles, which are some basic principles of object oriented programming and design.